# Prevent page refresh on linkbutton click

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am using a `LinkButton` inside `gridview` to open a popup on click of that `LinkButton`. However the popup appears for a second and vanishes on page load.
I want to avoid the page load.I can't use direct link as it will affect other features in my webpage. Please help. Thanks in advance

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID='lnkAbsent' OnClientClick='<%#"showModalPopup("+Eval("Category_ID")+","+Eval("Div_ID")+",1,"+Eval("AbsentStudent")+");"%>' Text='<%# Eval("AbsentStudent") %>' runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: can you please add some more code because single line is not enough to understand what is going on in your code

Comment: i used linkbutton using templatefield.@PranavPatel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with the following attribute and see if it works:

```
CausesValidation="False"
```

Another solution is as below, please try this one also:

Let's say your ASPX code is :

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="someID" runat="server" Text="clicky"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        someID.Attributes.Add("onClick", "return false;");
    }
}
```

What renders as HTML is

```
<a onclick="return false;" id="someID" href="javascript:__doPostBack('someID','')">clicky</a>
```

In this case, what happens is the onclick functionality becomes your validator. If it is false, the "href" link is not executed; however, if it is true the href will get executed. This eliminates your post back.

Comment: added one more solution in the answer, check if it works for you.

Comment: didn't work as the ID of my linkbutton can't be used in codebehind directly as it is inside gridview and it is not an independent control.

Comment: Try something like this : `...LinkButton ID="BtnForgotPassword" runat="server" OnClientClick="ChangeText('1');return false"...` and add `href="#"` attribute in your link button.

Comment: I used "someID.Attributes.Add("onClick", "return false;");" it in RowDataBound event of gridview and it worked. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use return false in your client method that will not fire postback event.

```
function showModalPopup(){
      ///do your stuff
      return false;
}
```

Or write something like.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID='lnkAbsent' OnClientClick='<%#"showModalPopup("+Eval("Category_ID")+","+Eval("Div_ID")+",1,"+Eval("AbsentStudent")+");"%>return false;' Text='<%# Eval("AbsentStudent") %>' runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: can you put your showmodalpopup code here in question?

Comment: That is because you are using ajax calls in the same success calls use return false.

Comment: I also tried return false; in the other functions which are getting called through function showModalPopup().

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `UpdatePanel` to avoid Page refresh.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>

        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```